# Getting a daily total execution count for each stored procedure, via Query Store tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-query-store

I'm trying to get a daily count of executions, of a particular stored procedure, via the Query Store tables. My original thought was that this should work:

```
SELECT 
    RunDate =  convert(varchar(10), first_execution_time,121) + ' ' + left(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, first_execution_time), 1)
    ,TotalExecutions = sum(rs.count_executions)
    ,TotalCPU = sum(round(rs.avg_cpu_time , 0) * rs.count_executions)
    ,TotalLogicalReads = sum(round(rs.avg_cpu_time , 0) * round(rs.avg_logical_io_reads ,0))
    ,TotalQueries  = count(distinct q.query_id)
    -- Comment out unless necessary...takes a long time
    -- ,ExecutionPlan = CAST(p.query_plan as XML)
FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats rs
JOIN sys.query_store_plan p ON p.plan_id = rs.plan_id
JOIN sys.query_store_query q ON q.query_id = p.query_id
WHERE 
    Object_Name(q.object_id) = 'API_SPName'
Group by  convert(varchar(10), first_execution_time,121) + ' ' + left(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, first_execution_time), 1) 
Order by RunDate desc
```

Then I realized that I'm over-counting the total executions if there are multiple separate SQL statements in the stored procedure.

I thought then that (assuming that there's 1 statement in the sp that would ALWAYS run, doesn't have an "if" around it) if I just took the QueryID that has the MOST total executions, and filter on that, it would give the total executions per day.

However, that's not working. When I run the following (similar to above but without grouping by day), after the most recent day, the QueryID is all the same! This is a procedure that has many statements in it. So, it should have many different QueryIDs.

```
SELECT 
    RunDate = convert(varchar(16), first_execution_time,121)
    ,TotalExecutions = rs.count_executions
     ,q.query_id
     ,p.plan_id
    ,AverageCPU  = round(rs.avg_cpu_time , 0)
    ,AverageLogicalReads  = round(rs.avg_logical_io_reads ,0)
    -- Comment out unless necessary...takes a long time
    -- ,ExecutionPlan = CAST(p.query_plan as XML)
FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats rs
JOIN sys.query_store_plan p ON p.plan_id = rs.plan_id
JOIN sys.query_store_query q ON q.query_id = p.query_id
WHERE 
    Object_Name(q.object_id) = 'API_SPName'
     -- and q.query_id =  3198102
Order by RunDate desc
```

Any thoughts on what might be going on here? Is there any other way to figure out how many times a stored procedure has been executed, daily?
Also as a side note - stored procedures that have just 1 statement seem to be accurate when I calculate the total number of executions per day

Comment: Consider capturing periodic snapshots of `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` into a table. The counters are cumulative and reset when the instance is restarted but you can still figure it out daily counts. I  do that every minute and find the info invaluable.

Comment: Side points: To truncate a date it's more efficient to use `cast(... as date)`. In your `GROUP BY` it's also more efficient to group by the actual values rather than the stringified form (you can stringify them afterwards) so you should do `GROUP BY CAST(first_execution_time AS date)` then work out the weekday in the `SELECT`